# Skipping long entries for history search in IPython 5.x

Tags: python, ipython, keyboard-shortcuts

I use `ipython` console quite heavily for python workflow. As happy as I am with the new 5.x series [released](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version5.html), I find the ability to freely navigate inside the long code blocks a double-edged sword when it comes to history search.

For example, typing `import f` and hitting the up key for history search completion now prompts the following to appear if there was a recent pasted code block that started with importing `foo`:

```
In [100]: import foo
     ...:
     ...: # copy-pasted code block that shows up in history
     ...: for foobar in foo.bar:
     ...:     pass
     ...:
```

Now if you were simply looking for a one line import statement, and if the code snippet in history is sufficiently long, that's a lot of lines to navigate upwards before you can switch to an earlier (desired) `import foo` in history.

So my question is, is there a shortcut that allows to skip a long history entry to the previous one? Browsing history with `Ctrl+R` is an obvious workaround for this issue, but I'd like to know if there's a way to get it to work with the up key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<Up>`/`<C-P>` and `<Down>`/`<C-N>` iterate over every line in your history.

Use `<PageDown>` and `<PageUp>` keys to iterate over entries instead.

Here's a full list of shortcuts: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/shortcuts/index.html.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, this is exactly what I've been looking for. Can't believe I missed it.